# Сортировка в Андроиде

Tags: android, сортировка, recyclerview, adapter

Есть общая сортировка по времени в двух фрагментах. (Все фиды, Избранные фиды). + в каждом из этих фрагментов прописана сортировка по дате(Все фиды) и сортировка по значению избранного (true/false).

Вот реализация Одного из фрагментов.

```
public class EverythingFeedFragment extends BaseFeedFragment {
private BroadcastReceiver eventsRequestDoneReceiver;

public static EverythingFeedFragment newInstance() {
    return new EverythingFeedFragment();
}

public EverythingFeedFragment() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    eventsRequestDoneReceiver = createEventsRequestDoneReceiver();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getContext()).registerReceiver(eventsRequestDoneReceiver, new IntentFilter(BroadcastIntents.EVENTS_REQUEST_OK));
    HappRestClient.getInstance().getEvents();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateEventsList();
}

protected void updateEventsList() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<Event> eventRealmResults = realm.where(Event.class).findAllSorted("startDate", Sort.ASCENDING);
    events = (ArrayList<Event>)realm.copyFromRealm(eventRealmResults.subList(0, eventRealmResults.size()));
    ((EventsListAdapter)eventsListView.getAdapter()).updateData(events);
    realm.close();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (eventsRequestDoneReceiver != null) {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(App.getContext()).unregisterReceiver(eventsRequestDoneReceiver);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void getEvents(int page) {
    APIService.getEvents(page);
}

 private BroadcastReceiver createEventsRequestDoneReceiver() {
    return new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateEventsList();
        }
    };
 }
}
```

Кто знает, как можно сделать по клику на кнопку, другую сортировку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

выполнить по клику на кнопку метод

```
protected void updateEventsList() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<Event> eventRealmResults = realm.where(Event.class).findAllSorted("startDate", Sort.ASCENDING);
    events = (ArrayList<Event>)realm.copyFromRealm(eventRealmResults.subList(0, eventRealmResults.size()));
    ((EventsListAdapter)eventsListView.getAdapter()).updateData(events);
    realm.close();
}
```

, Но передать в `findAllSorted` другое поле для сортировки. Можете, например, добавить в этот метод параметр:

```
protected void updateEventsList(String sortField) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<Event> eventRealmResults = realm.where(Event.class).findAllSorted(sortField, Sort.ASCENDING);
    events = (ArrayList<Event>)realm.copyFromRealm(eventRealmResults.subList(0, eventRealmResults.size()));
    ((EventsListAdapter)eventsListView.getAdapter()).updateData(events);
    realm.close();
}
```

И потом по клику вызывать его с тем полем сортировки, которым надо:

```
updateEventsList("startDate");
```

Comment: но у меня есть некоторые значения true/false. Sort.ASCENDING, уже не подойдет. Как можно его заменять на true или false?

Comment: @SatanistDevilov, добавьте еще один параметр в метод, и передавайте туда то, что вам нужно.